# ssmtp and logcheck

Tags: ssmtp

Ubuntu 18.04
ssmtp is running, and following command works correctly:

```
echo "This is a test" | mail -s "test subject" username@gmail.com
```

username@gmail.com receives the message via gmail, but message appears to be from
root@[servername]
which surprisingly the SMTP gateway is OK with.  But when logcheck runs, I get an error:

```
Jun 15 18:02:03 [servername] sSMTP[13901]: 550 5.1.0 <logcheck@> invalid address 'logcheck@'
Jun 15 18:02:03 [servername] sSMTP[13901]: SSL connection using ECDHE_RSA_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
Jun 15 18:02:02 [servername] sSMTP[13901]: Creating SSL connection to host
```

So how do I convince logcheck to send as "logcheck@servername" instead of just "logcheck@" ??

ETA:

Everything in logcheck.conf is commented out except:

```
REPORTLEVEL="server"
SENDMAILTO="[myemail]@gmail.com"
MAILASATTACH=0
FQDN=1
TMP="/tmp"
```

Comment: can you paste your logcheck config files?

Comment: Apparently `ssmtp` is deprecated. If so, try `msntp`. I find it easier to use with gmail.